# How to encrypt a file using PGP Hex ID and PGP Name instead of a public key file in C#

Tags: c#, bouncycastle, pgp

I am currently working on a application which will create a text file, encrypt the file using PGP public key(which is not a file but a hexadecimal number and a pgp name) and post it to an FTP on schedule. The person whom I post the information to needs the file to be PGP encrypted and has shared the public key(which is not a file but a hexadecimal number and a pgp name).

The place where I am stuck is the PGP encryption part. I see examples on how to encrypt a text file using a public key file or public key ring(which I understand is a set of keys) using bouncy castle library. But the information I have is a 32 bit hexa decimal key and a PGP name. I am not sure how exactly to encrypt the file using this information. Should I request the other party to send me the public key file? Is it possible to create the public key file from the information I have? I am pretty new to PGP encryption and am posting this after a lot of googling which didnt provide any information, so please help.

This is the code I have so far to encrypt file. As you can see the code takes the file as an input for the public key not a hexa decimal code and name. My question really is, is it even possible to do a pgp encryption using a pgp name and a hexa decimal number?

```
public class PGPHelper
{
    private PgpEncryptionKeys m_encryptionKeys;
    private const int BufferSize = 0x10000;
    /// <summary>
    /// Instantiate a new PgpEncrypt class with initialized PgpEncryptionKeys.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="encryptionKeys"></param>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException">encryptionKeys is null</exception>
    public PGPHelper(PgpEncryptionKeys encryptionKeys)
    {
        if (encryptionKeys == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("encryptionKeys", "encryptionKeys is null.");
        }
        m_encryptionKeys = encryptionKeys;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Encrypt and sign the file pointed to by unencryptedFileInfo and
    /// write the encrypted content to outputStream.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="outputStream">The stream that will contain the
    /// encrypted data when this method returns.</param>
    /// <param name="fileName">FileInfo of the file to encrypt</param>
    public void Encrypt(Stream outputStream, FileInfo unencryptedFileInfo)
    {
        if (outputStream == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("outputStream", "outputStream is null.");
        }
        if (unencryptedFileInfo == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("unencryptedFileInfo", "unencryptedFileInfo is null.");
        }
        if (!File.Exists(unencryptedFileInfo.FullName))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("File to encrypt not found.");
        }
        using (Stream encryptedOut = ChainEncryptedOut(outputStream))
        {
            using (Stream literalOut = ChainLiteralOut(encryptedOut, unencryptedFileInfo))
            using (FileStream inputFile = unencryptedFileInfo.OpenRead())
            {
                WriteOutput(literalOut, inputFile);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void WriteOutput(Stream literalOut,
        FileStream inputFile)
    {
        int length = 0;
        byte[] buf = new byte[BufferSize];
        while ((length = inputFile.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length)) > 0)
        {
            literalOut.Write(buf, 0, length);
        }
    }

    private Stream ChainEncryptedOut(Stream outputStream)
    {
        PgpEncryptedDataGenerator encryptedDataGenerator;
        encryptedDataGenerator =
            new PgpEncryptedDataGenerator(SymmetricKeyAlgorithmTag.TripleDes, new SecureRandom());
        encryptedDataGenerator.AddMethod(m_encryptionKeys.PublicKey);
        return encryptedDataGenerator.Open(outputStream, new byte[BufferSize]);
    }

    private static Stream ChainLiteralOut(Stream encryptedOut, FileInfo file)
    {
        PgpLiteralDataGenerator pgpLiteralDataGenerator = new PgpLiteralDataGenerator();
        return pgpLiteralDataGenerator.Open(encryptedOut, PgpLiteralData.Binary, file);
    }

}

public class PgpEncryptionKeys
{

    public PgpPublicKey PublicKey { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the EncryptionKeys class.
    /// Two keys are required to encrypt and sign data. Your private key and the recipients public key.
    /// The data is encrypted with the recipients public key and signed with your private key.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="publicKeyPath">The key used to encrypt the data</param>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentException">Public key not found. Private key not found. Missing password</exception>
    public PgpEncryptionKeys(string publicKeyPath, string privateKeyPath, string passPhrase)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(publicKeyPath))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Public key file not found", "publicKeyPath");
        }
        PublicKey = ReadPublicKey(publicKeyPath);
    }

    #region Public Key

    private PgpPublicKey ReadPublicKey(string publicKeyPath)
    {
        using (Stream keyIn = File.OpenRead(publicKeyPath))
        using (Stream inputStream = PgpUtilities.GetDecoderStream(keyIn))
        {
            PgpPublicKeyRingBundle publicKeyRingBundle = new PgpPublicKeyRingBundle(inputStream);
            PgpPublicKey foundKey = GetFirstPublicKey(publicKeyRingBundle);
            if (foundKey != null)
            {
                return foundKey;
            }
        }
        throw new ArgumentException("No encryption key found in public key ring.");
    }

    private PgpPublicKey GetFirstPublicKey(PgpPublicKeyRingBundle publicKeyRingBundle)
    {
        foreach (PgpPublicKeyRing kRing in publicKeyRingBundle.GetKeyRings())
        {
            PgpPublicKey key = kRing.GetPublicKeys()
                .Cast<PgpPublicKey>()
                .Where(k => k.IsEncryptionKey)
                .FirstOrDefault();

            if (key != null)
            {
                return key;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    #endregion
```

Comment: Can you show  the code that you have currently as well as point out exactly where you are stuck, if you do indeed have any code..? also Google Search `C# PGP`[C# with PGP](http://www.google.com)

Comment: The person must give you his public key. The key is long (a kylobyte or more), so giving you a hex number and any name doesn't make sense.

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp thats what I figured too wanted to make sure the information I have is insufficient before asking for the key from the other person. We basically work for 2 different companies I need to post information on their site and they want the file to be encrypted.

Comment: The hex number is probably the key ID. It can be used to look up the key in a keyring, or from a keyserver. The lookup step gets you the actual key. You would need to be provided with the keyring or the URL of the keyserver.

Comment: There was some transition going on through my company and it was difficult to get hold of people. I am glad to tell you that I finally got the Public key file. Thanks a lot for clarifying things